# Stop Button inside a For loop

Tags: java, button, for-loop, break

I have been looking around for a stop button but I can't find anything that applies to my code.

```
if (O1.isSelected()) {
    for (int nu = Num; nu > 0; nu--) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.delay(Num2 * 1000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking of making the jbutton initiate a break; but I can't seem to use jButtonActionPerformed inside a for loop. Any help is greatly apriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Create the jButtonActionPerformed event outside the loop and have it set a global variable, then add a condition in your loop to check the value of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button's click handler set a private field to indicate that the action has been "stopped", then make your `for` loop check for that field when it is at a safe place to cancel:

```
for (int nu = Num; nu > 0; nu--) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(Num2 * 1000);
        if (this.stopRequested) {
            this.stopRequested = !this.stopRequested;
            break;
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the stopRequested variable should be declared as `volatile`

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are saying, could you explain in a bit more detail please?

Comment: @NickHaughton: What aspect do you not understand?

Comment: I do not understand what i would do under the jButton1ActionPerformed.

Comment: @NickHaughton: You would set `stopRequested` to `true`. How you would do this depends on how that handler method's class is scoped in relation to the code with this `for` loop.